Convexity of $\ln(a^\top x) - \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i) $
Given $f:\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $f(x)=ln(a^\top x) - \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}$, where also $a\in \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}$. Is the function $f(x)$ convex?
I need it to be convex as a part of a bigger proof. I can plot it when $n=2$ and I see that it is convex, yet I am struggling to formally prove it. Any hint or idea is welcome!

I got nerdsniped here, but note that generally your questions need to provide more context, and explicitly describe your attempts at the problem. Else you're liable to accrue downvotes and get your question closed.

Yes, "logarithm of sum of monomial reciprocals" is even conic (DCP) representable, which can be shown by following the same technique as in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/expo.html#log-sum-inv

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965417/boyd-vandenberghe-problem-3-49-c-proving-that-a-function-is-log-concave

Well, we can compute the Hessian. Let $f_a$ denote the map with given $a$. Then $$ \partial_i f_a = \frac{a_i}{a^\top x} - \frac{1}{x_i}$$ and $$\partial_i\partial_j f_a = -\frac{a_i a_j}{(a^\top x)^2}  + \frac{1}{x_i^2}\delta_{ij},$$ where $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise.
So, for any vector $v$, $$ \varphi(v,x;a) := v^\top \mathrm{Hess}(f_a) v = \sum_i \frac{v_i^2}{x_i^2} - \frac{(a^\top v)^2}{(a^\top x)^2}.$$
Convexity of $f_a$ is equivalent to $\varphi(v,x;a)$ being nonnegative for all $v,x$. Now, write $u_i = v_i/x_i$ and $b_i = a_i x_i$. Then it suffices to show that for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n,b \in \mathbb{R}^n > 0,$ $$ \frac{(\sum b_i)^2 \sum u_i^2 - (\sum b_i u_i)^2 }{(\sum b_i)^2} \overset{?}\ge 0.$$
But, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $(\sum b_i u_i)^2 \le (\sum b_i^2) (\sum u_i^2),$ and so $$ \frac{(\sum b_i)^2 \sum u_i^2 - (\sum b_i u_i)^2 }{(\sum b_i)^2} \ge \frac{\sum u_i^2}{(\sum b_i)^2} \cdot \left( (\sum b_i)^2 - \sum b_i^2\right) \ge \frac{\sum u_i^2}{(\sum b_i)^2} \cdot \sum_{i\neq j} b_i b_j \ge 0,$$ where the final inequality uses that $b_i > 0$ for all $i$, and we're done. Notice that this holds no matter what $a$ is, and so $f_a$ is convex for every $a$.
